# Apache 2.2 rewriterule over-binding

Tags: apache-http-server, regex

I have a problem with a RewriteRule where it appears to be over-binding in the REGEX:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4,6}(?:-[0-9]{1,2})?\.jpg)$     /cgi-bin/logo-image.pl?image=$1 [L,PT]
```

What it should do is bind a 4-6 digit number, followed by an optional `-`, a 1-2 digit number and `.jpg`, at the end of the URL, and send them as a query string to the backend.  It works fine unless there is another 4-6 digit number in the URL, e.g.,

```
https://site.url/images-sold/foo-bar-498-24340-1.jpg
```

works, calling `/cgi-bin/logo-image.pl?image=24340-1.jpg`,
but

```
https://site.url/images-sold/foo-bar-49899-24340-1.jpg
```

calls `/cgi-bin/logo-image.pl?image=49899-24340-1.jpg`. 
I verified the regex as valid PCRE; what am I missing?

Comment: Does it work better with a caret `^` at the beginning of the regex? `RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4,6}(?:-[0-9]{1,2})?\.jpg)$     /cgi-bin/logo-image.pl?image=$1 [L,PT]`

Comment: It's not the start of the string, so a ^ won't match properly.  the URI looks like `images-sold/foo-bar-49899-24340-1.jpg`

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it doesn't provide a solution to your problem.